# Is it possible to combine "docker logs" output and "docker exec" output?

Tags: docker

Is it possible that merging `docker logs -f` output and `docker exec` result?
I already tried to redirect `docker exec` results to `docker logs` file. My environment that host is MacOS and run ubuntu docker image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run

```
docker exec -it <container id> sh -c "ls -alh  > /proc/1/fd/1"
```

`sh -c` is required so that your shell doesn't interpret the redirection

Comment: ! Thank you so much! I am searching the solution for hours and finally make it!